# Azure AD Graph API - Assigning a group with role to a tenant's application (ServicePrincipal)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

All,

I am trying to assign a group to an application (that my company doesn't own, Box) in my tenant. I downloaded the Graph Console App V3 from 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console and have looked at the code.  My code below seems to follow the example, the only difference is that I want to do this all as the application and not require user consent. When I attempt to run the console app in "app mode", it fails with a permissions issue.  So, I just wrote the code below, am not getting permissions issues, but am getting another error (see my comments inline).

I am using Java, not .NET, but I wanted to use Fiddler to see what the request is since I wasn't having much luck in Java manually creating the request.

Still, I am not having any luck in .NET using the `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient` either.  Here is my code.  My tenant has a single-tenant company owned application with application permissions given to "Windows Azure Active Directory".

```
try
{

    var servicePrincipals = await client.ServicePrincipals.ExecuteAsync();
    var servicePrincipal = (ServicePrincipal)servicePrincipals.CurrentPage
        .SingleOrDefault(sp => sp.AppDisplayName == "Box");

    while (servicePrincipal == null && servicePrincipals.MorePagesAvailable)
    {
        await servicePrincipals.GetNextPageAsync();
        servicePrincipal = (ServicePrincipal)servicePrincipals.CurrentPage
            .SingleOrDefault(sp => sp.AppDisplayName == "Box");
    }

    if (servicePrincipal != null)
    {
        var spfetcher = (servicePrincipal as IServicePrincipalFetcher);

        // returns the correct information and all guids align properly with the correct servicePrincipal,
        // Id (appRole) and principalId for the group
        var appRoleAssignments = await spfetcher.AppRoleAssignedTo.ExecuteAsync();

        // data returned by call above
        //CreationTimestamp         null
        //Id                        {efxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
        //PrincipalDisplayName      "TestGroup"
        //PrincipalId               {39xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
        //PrincipalType             "Group"
        //ResourceDisplayName       "Box"
        //ResourceId                {11xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}


        // I have a group called "Manually Added" that want to assign to this application with
        // the first role that the service principal has
        var groups = await client.Groups.ExecuteAsync();
        var group = (Group)groups.CurrentPage.SingleOrDefault(g => g.DisplayName.Contains("Manual"));
        while (group == null && groups.MorePagesAvailable)
        {
            await groups.GetNextPageAsync();
            group = (Group)groups.CurrentPage.SingleOrDefault(g => g.DisplayName.Contains("Manual"));
        }

        if (group != null)
        {
            // Tried this way, seems to be correct as far as the documentation and examples
            AppRoleAssignment appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment();

            // just use a known appRole id for this example
            appRoleAssignment.Id = servicePrincipal.AppRoles.FirstOrDefault().Id;

            // the service principal to add the group with the app role
            appRoleAssignment.ResourceId = Guid.Parse(servicePrincipal.ObjectId);

            // principal is a group (named ManuallyAdded)
            appRoleAssignment.PrincipalType = "Group";

            // the id of the group (ManuallyAdded)
            appRoleAssignment.PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(group.ObjectId);

            // Tried this way, no luck Bad Request (400) with "not a valid reference update"
            servicePrincipal.AppRoleAssignments.Add(appRoleAssignment);
            await servicePrincipal.UpdateAsync();

            // Tried this way, same thing as above
            //var spfetcher = (servicePrincipal as IServicePrincipalFetcher);
            //var appRoleAssignments = await spfetcher.AppRoleAssignedTo.ExecuteAsync();
            await spfetcher.AppRoleAssignments.AddAppRoleAssignmentAsync(appRoleAssignment);

            // Tried this way, same thing as above
            // var groupFetcher = (group as IGroupFetcher);
            // await groupFetcher.AppRoleAssignments.AddAppRoleAssignmentAsync(appRoleAssignment);

            // Tried flipping the resourceId and the principalId, to assign the app through the group 
            // AddAppRoleAssignmentAsync.  Same error
            //appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment();
            //appRoleAssignment.Id = servicePrincipal.AppRoles.FirstOrDefault().Id;
            //appRoleAssignment.ResourceId = Guid.Parse(group.ObjectId);
            //appRoleAssignment.PrincipalType = "Group";
            //appRoleAssignment.PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(servicePrincipal.ObjectId);

            //// Tried this way, same thing as above
            //var groupFetcher = (group as IGroupFetcher);
            //await groupFetcher.AppRoleAssignments.AddAppRoleAssignmentAsync(appRoleAssignment);     
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Program.WriteError("Error: {0}", Program.ExtractErrorMessage(e));
}
```

Permissions granted in Azure:

[image: Permissions granted in Azure]

Thanks!
Brian

**UPDATE**

Here is what is in my access token

```js
{
  "aud": "https://graph.windows.net",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenantId>/",
  "iat": 1480449285,
  "nbf": 1480449285,
  "exp": 1480453185,
  "appid": "<appId>",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "e_exp": 10800,
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenantId>/",
  "oid": "xxxxxx-0b62-4d91-8853-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "roles": [
    "Device.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.Read.All",
    "Member.Read.Hidden",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "Domain.ReadWrite.All"
  ],
  "sub": "xxxxxx-0b62-4d91-8853-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "tid": "<tenantId>",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Here is the code that is throwing the permissions issue (this is modified code found in the graphapi-console that I linked above), but calls the existing methods in the GraphRequest.cs

```cs
 // the exception occurs in CreateNewApplication.  
 // But in my case, I have already loaded the existing servicePrincipal
 var newApp = await CreateNewApplication(client);
 var newServicePrincipal = await CreateServicePrincipal(client, newApp);
 await AssignAppRole(client, newApp, newServicePrincipal);
```

Which causes:

```js
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the scope claims "scp" in your access token? Also could you share the same information in the flow where you get a permission issue?

Comment: I have updated my question to add the access token information and the requested code that is causing a permission exception. @ShawnTabrizi

Answer (score 0):

To assign the role to application for the specific group. We need to update the specific **Group** instead of **Application**. Here is the request for your reference:

```
POST: https://graph.windows.net/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/directoryObjects/{GroupId}/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Group/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
Authorization: Bearer {token}
{
    "id": "{roleId}",
    "odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.AppRoleAssignment",
    "principalId":"{groupId}",
    "principalType":"Group",
    "resourceId":"{principalId}"
}
```

### Update

To fix the 403 error about *Insufficient privileges to complete the operation* we need to use the command below  which using the [Azure ActiveDirectory (MSOnline)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/msonline/) to assign the **Company Administrator** role to the application.

```
Connect-MsolService
$ClientIdWebApp = '{your_AD_application_client_id}'
$webApp = Get-MsolServicePrincipal –AppPrincipalId $ClientIdWebApp
#use Add-MsolRoleMember to add it to "Company Administrator" role).
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleName "Company Administrator" -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal -RoleMemberObjectId $webApp.ObjectId
```

Comment: This is partially correct for my question above.  This handles the case for adding an appRole assignment, but not for the access denied when creating an application.

Comment: Based on the test, to fix this issue we can assign the **Company Administrator** role to the application. I modified the post to append the command to assign this role, you can check whether it is helpful.

Comment: I wish we could get some more permissions in Azure AD for doing stuff. Having to make a service principal a Company Admin is quite a bad thing.

Comment: @juunas If you any idea or feedback about Azure, you can submit it from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full answer I ended up coming up with.

For creating the appRoleAssignment:

```
private static final String RESOURCE_BASE_URL = "https://graph.windows.net";
private static final String GROUPS_RESOURCE_SET = "groups";
private static final String PRINCIPAL_TYPE = "Group";
// use this if you want to assign a User
// private static final String PRINCIPAL_TYPE = "User";

private static final String API_VERSION = "api-version=1.6";

private String tenantName = "<your tenant name (domain) or id>"
private String appRoleId = "<some appRoleId (from the applications appRoles list or Empty UUID>"
private String servicePrincipalId = "<your servicePrincipalId for the assignment>"
private String principalId = "<your user or group id>"

// empty UUID for appRoleId means no app roles initially (default access)
String postData = String.format(
    "{\n" +
            "\"id\": \"%s\"," +
            "\"principalId\": \"%s\"," +
            "\"principalType\": \"%s\"," +
            "\"resourceId\": \"%s\"" +
            "}", appRoleId, principalId,
    PRINCIPAL_TYPE, servicePrincipalId);

String urlString = String.format("%s/%s/%s/%s/appRoleAssignments?%s", RESOURCE_BASE_URL,
        tenantName, GROUPS_RESOURCE_SET, <group objectId>, API_VERSION);
```

The permissions issue with programmatically creating an Application on my tenant was confusing.  After a decent amount of searching, it seems that the Application (Service Principal) needs to have a Company Administrator role (or a role with enough permissions). I wasn't able to do it through the portal or through the AD Graph API, although there may be a way to do this. Instead, it seems you have to use a Powershell script. I found this online in a couple of places (different variations) and after some trial and error, narrowed it down to this.

```
# -------------------------------
# Connect and request credentials
# --------------------------------
Connect-MsolService

# ------------------------------------------------
# Get the service principal objectId for the specified app
# -----------------------------------------------
$appDisplayName = "<your app name>"
$objectId = (Get-MsolServicePrincipal -SearchString $appDisplayName).ObjectId

# ------------------------------------------------
# Assign the company admin role to the service principal
# -----------------------------------------------
$tenantRoleName = "Company Administrator"              
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleName $tenantRoleName -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal -RoleMemberObjectId $objectId
```

It was a little bit confusing as to which module(s) to install.  I tracked down exactly what I needed to get the right cmdlets. It seems the MSOnline module gives everything you need to run this script.  In the event it doesn't, install the AzureAD module (Or AzureADPreview moldule) if you get an error.  These are the best steps I found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/msonline/

Brian